# TypeError: this.f is not a constructor | firebase.auth()

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase cloud function to signup the user.

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const newUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
    handle: req.body.handle
  };

  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err});
    })
    .then(data => {
      return res
        .status(201)
        .json({ message: `user ${data.user.uid} signed up successfully` });
    });
});
```

but I think `then` block is never executed I tried to debug by changing the catch block and everytime `catch` block is executed.
when I looked up the logs of the firebase functions I found this.

```
TypeError: this.f is not a constructor
    at ai.a (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:188:361)
    at yh (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:171:191)
    at bi.o (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:193:175)
    at ji (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:191:239)
    at /srv/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:197:181
    at new C (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:18:736)
    at pi (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:197:161)
    at /srv/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:209:203
    at e.g (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:22:101)
    at Kb (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:25:195)
```

Comment: I deleted my node_modules folder and reinstall everything one at a time starting with Firebase. Not sure where the problem actually lies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install new version of firebase

```
npm i firebase@6.2.3-1
```

or

```
yarn add firebase@6.2.3-1
```

fix this bug.